# Do photons move as waves

Tags: photons

**Photon**.

I am curious about the movement of photons.Do they move in *wave motion (up and down)* or do they move in *straight lines*

Comment: Photons, as any wave, propagate in a line. What it is usually depicted in books is the transverse oscillation of the electromagnetic field.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that you are shaking a rope, the rope moves up and down but do not be mistaken: the wave is not what is moving up and down, it's the rope. The wave goes only forward, so do photons. Curiously enough, if you go down the theory of relativity 'straight lines' can be defined by the path of light beams.